# Like to show all the labels of x axis in highchart

Tags: highcharts

I like to show all months which are on the x-axis even if don't have corresponding data. As in my case, I have data till Sep therefore following months are not being displayed.

I'm using highchart in my application with angular 4.
[image: example graph]

Comment: Unfortunately we can't help you if you don't share some code with us.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536733/display-12-months-on-highcharts-xaxis

Comment: Please make sure your question provides a [mcve] so we can try to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `xAxis.max` to `11` (categories have indexes starting from 0) to achieve the desired result.

**API reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max